# Как сделать такой сайт: Суть работы

Tags: jquery, веб-дизайн, css

[Ссылка](http://www.creaktif.com/)

Только что встретил вот такой сайт. Стало интересно, как он функционирует. Может кто то описать принцип работы и как реализовать(подсказки, в какую сторону смотреть)? Буду благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, вот подсказка: http://htmlbook.ru/css/transform

Comment: А скролл каким образом обрабатывается?

Comment: а вот таким: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/